# How to make a typing indicator using AWS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm new in AWS and i'm discovering some modules like AWS Lambda, dynamodb, SNS, cloudsearch etc.

I'm wondering how to set up a chat typing indicator. Meaning that in the chat interface a little text (or animated icon) show up in the bottom to inform you in real-time that your chat partner is typing a message.

That's sound relatively simple to explain but i have to admit that i have some difficulties to conceive the setting up of this function using aws instruments.

Any explications and good advices will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Though you have asked how to do this with Amazon Web Services, I would like to think this has more to do with socket based programming than AWS.

For example, normally, chat applications or in general, real time applications are built using sockets.

Javascript can help you detect key stroke events in which case you can show the other user a notification that the recipient is typing.

Similarly, if a backspace key is pressed, you know the message is being erased.

This is ofcourse a simple algorithm and there is a lot of room for optimization.

For a start, you can learn how to set up socket server using the AWS EC2 service.

Comment: thanks. I did know sockets that i used until i discovered aws. I wanted to find out a way so that my app would be a 100% aws made. But if i really can't conceive such a thing with aws tools so i will have to consider to get back to my socket lib.